# Why would a P-Trap be required before an air gap for a refrigerator drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain

**Background:**

A walk-in refrigerator with a remote refrigeration system includes an evaporator coil that requires a drain. The typical installation is an indirect drain (terminating above a funnel drain or floor sink to provide an air gap).

Location: USA and Canada

**Observation:**

I have recently seen installations and plans calling for an S-trap in the indirect drain line BEFORE the funnel drain/air gap.

`[Evap Coil] ===/ /=== [S-Trap][Air Gap][Funnel Drain]====>`

[image: drain schematic]
*Image Source: [HeatCraftrpd.com](https://www.heatcraftrpd.com/contentAsset/raw-data/59aa2440-c0f7-4dde-9294-2ab09cba60ef/fileAsset?byInode=true&force_download=true)*

My understanding was that traps provide a barrier of water that blocks gasses from entering the room through the drain.

**Question:**

What purpose does a trap serve immediately before an air gap?

Comment: This might help as well as the accepted answer: https://hvacbasics.com/condensate-drains-and-traps/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's preventing **air movement through the drain pipe.** Without it, cold air from the refrigerated space will constantly flow out the pipe, and warm air from outside will constantly leak in - wasting your refrigeration energy/expense.

So, it's doing exactly what you understand, but your understanding was perhaps limited to the case of "sewer gas" while in this case that's handled beyond the air-gapped drain, and the "gas" being prevented from moving is air - warm or cold.

Comment: You can also get negative pressure preventing the condensate from flowing out.  Instead is will accumulate in the unit and eventually leak inside the building.